# CodeIgniter radio button value into existing database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, radio-button

i develop a program that one of the function is, if you tick the 'yes' in the radio button, the whole row will show in the next page.

The problem is, i tried to insert the radio button value in my database, but the database need whole value for my table, which i already have in my original database (i only want to insert the radio button value into the column).

This is my code

Controller:

```
public function verify()
{
    $password2 = $this->input->post('password2');
    log_message('error','isi password : '.$password2);
    $return = $this->welcome_model->checkPassword($password2);

    $data=$this->welcome_model;
    $data->verif=$this->input->post("rad$id");
    $data->insert_radio($id);

    if($return){


        redirect('welcome/success');
    }
    else{
        redirect('welcome/masuk');
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function insert_radio($id){
    $data=(array)$this;
    $this->db->insert("info",$data);
}
```

View:

```
 <div class="radio">
                <label>
                 <input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $row->id;?>]"/>
                  Yes
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $row->id;?>]"/>
                  No
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are u looking for update ? https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#update

Comment: ah yes! i was using a wrong syntax all this time, i should be using 'update' instead of 'insert', thanks!

Comment: `$id` variable in controller seems not to be initialized anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the table which is already having a value then use the following

```
$this->db
->set('name', 'value')
->set('name', 'value')
->where('condition_name', 'condtion_value')
->update()
```

In case if your having any issue with HTML you can use the following

Instead of

```
<input type="radio" name="rad[<?php echo $row->id;?>]"/>
```

Use the following way

```
<input type="radio" name="radio_name" value="rad[<?php echo $row->id;?>]"/>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this but i can't get the specific row that i want to select. i did your advice and my whole data changed to a duplicate data.